# Блок с img со свойствами как у background

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать блок у которого картинка будет заполнять всю его ширину или высоту также как background
Стоит задача — **именно картинкой тегом img**.
Вот то - что нужно получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расположение элементов решается с помощью grid и flex - это сделано, а вот как с картинками, как их обрезать не используя backgraund?

Comment: в смысле за вас сделать надо что ли ?

Comment: `background-size background-position`  используй

Comment: нужно обойтись без backgraund, а конкретно тегом <img>
c фоном сделать понятно как

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  max-width: 920px;
}

.svg-image-grid {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  max-width: 920px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}


/** Screen readers only class from Bootstrap */

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  border: 0;
}


/** Actual code examples */


/** Background */

.image-bg {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-bg-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}


/** Object-fit */

.image-fit {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-fit-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-fit-img {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/** Absolute positioning */

.image {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-img {
  left: 50%;
  max-height: 150%;
  max-width: 177%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/** SVG */

.image-svg {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: calc(25% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.image-svg svg {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/** Responsive grid */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .image,
  .image-fit,
  .image-bg,
  .image-svg {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
  .image-svg {
    padding-bottom: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Изображение как background</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

</div>

<h2>Параметры object-fit</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-fit" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-fit-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-fit-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using object-fit example" />
  </a>

</div>

<h2>Изображение с абсолютным позиционированием</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-img" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image using absolute positioning example" />
  </a>

</div>

<h2>Изображение внутри SVG</h2>

<div class="svg-image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-svg" target="_blank">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" role="img">
      <title>Cropped image using SVG example</title>
      <image xlink:href="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </svg>
  </a>

</div>
```

Подробности читайте [тут](https://auralinna.blog/post/2018/crop-and-resize-images-with-css). Код в примере взят оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

ваш вопрос скорее о aspect-ratio у фото ... смотрите я попытался так реализовать , три варианта

> смотреть на весь экран: так как задачи адаптировать не было

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper1 .items1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.wrapper1 .items1 .item-img {
  width: 50%;
}

.wrapper1 .items2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.wrapper1 .items2 .item-img {
  order: 1;
}

.wrapper1 .items2 .item-img img {
  height: 40vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper1 .items2 .item-text {
  order: 2;
}

.wrapper1 .items3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper1 .items3 .item-img {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper1 .items3 .item-img img {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.item-text {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="items items1">
    <div class="item-text">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic laborum laboriosam eius recusandae et, numquam dolorem reprehenderit unde illum pariatur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="http://push-foto.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Girl-in-summer-relaxation-nature-grass_1920x1200.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="items items2">
    <div class="item-text">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic laborum laboriosam eius recusandae et, numquam dolorem reprehenderit unde illum pariatur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="http://push-foto.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Girl-in-summer-relaxation-nature-grass_1920x1200.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="items items3">
    <div class="item-text">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic laborum laboriosam eius recusandae et, numquam dolorem reprehenderit unde illum pariatur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="http://push-foto.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Girl-in-summer-relaxation-nature-grass_1920x1200.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените к картинке `<img>` стиль `object-fit:cover`, если хотите заполнения картинкой без искажений (тогда будет обрезка), или `object-fit:fill` (без обрезки, но с искажением пропорций, если у картинки и контейнера они отличаются). Всё.

Comment: Это будет лучший ответ когда Windows7 перестанут использовать.  
https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: Поставьте Chrome на семерку =)